# When $F(t)=\int_0^tf(s)ds$ is differentiable everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, lebesgue-integral, almost-everywhere

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is continuous almost everywhere.

1) Is the function $F(t)=\int_0^tf(s)ds$ differentiable everywhere ?

2) What is the "weakest"  condition on $f$ (in general) that makes $F(t)=\int_0^tf(s)ds$ differentiable everywhere ? $f$ continuous ?

Comment: **NB:** differentiable and derivable are different words.